# Google Apps Script: Keep getting array variable is undefined

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an Apps Script on a Google Sheet where when I try to assign a value to an array entry, I get an error that the array is not defined.  If I set a breakpoint one line above this line, though, I can see the array declaration in the variables window.  How can I fix the syntax to write this array entry?  Thank you!

The last line below is where the error is triggered.

```js
function assignMonitors(){
  //function to count # of break-out monitors per half-hour
  var startCol = 9; //col I is 1st column with half-hours listed
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  if(ActiveSheet.getName() == "Calculator"){
    //get the values from row 13, cols 9 - end:
    var colRange = ActiveSheet.getLastColumn() - startCol + 1;
    var row = 13;
    var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(row,startCol,1,colRange);
    var rangeLength = WholeRange.getWidth();
    var allValues = WholeRange.getValues(); //this is the read array
    var tempList = new Array(rangeLength); //this is the write array
    for(var i = 0; i < rangeLength; i++){
      var previousCell = ActiveSheet.getRange(row,(startCol+i-1));
      var currentCol = ActiveSheet.getRange(13, (startCol + i)).getValue();
      var cell = ActiveSheet.getRange(11,(startCol + i));
      //get the remaining number of available columns:
      var maxOffset = ActiveSheet.getLastColumn() - (startCol + i);
      //if the remaining number of available columns is >8, set to 8:
      if(maxOffset > 8){
        maxOffset = 8;
      }
      var newRange = 0;
      var writeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), cell.getColumn(), 1, colRange); //this is the range to which to write the write array
      //if this is the 1st column of hours:
      if(i == 0){
        for(newRange = 0; newRange < 9; newRange++){
          templist[newRange] = currentCol;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `templist[]` and `tempList[]` are **not** the same array.

`templist[newRange] = currentCol;`

should be:

`tempList[newRange] = currentCol;`

JavaScript, and by extension, Google Apps Script, is a **case-sensitive** language and care should be taken when capital letters are used.

**Reference:**

[JavaScript Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp)

Comment: Wow, dumb mistake!  Thank you so much, I've been looking at this for hours and ignored the obvious!

Comment: Very much appreciated!